# How to use MongoDB in a vanillaJS project

Tags: no-framework

I want to implement a CRUD mongoDB functionality into my web app witch only has HTML,CSS and vanilla JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't , but more important is that **you shouldn't**.

MongoDB is a server database and you should connect to it with some kind of backend. So, you need to use something like Java, PHP, Node, etc. to connect to MongoDB. The right way to do this is to build some API that you can consume using JS (like a REST endpoint).

Even if you could find a way to connect to MongoDB using JS, you would be exposing YOUR WHOLE DATABASE to anyone who has a web browser and access to the URL. Also, if you want it to be accesible from anywhere, you would need to allow ANY IP address to connect to the server. DON'T EVER DO THAT. DON'T YOU EVER EXPOSE YOUR WHOLE DATABASE TO THE INTERNET

Comment: Wait, I don't think it is fair to just deny this genuine question like this... Like, OP might wanted to create a dashboard for internal use that would modify their database. The thing is, there are actual use cases for doing this...

Comment: Yes, you may want to do that, but there are just some better ways and more secure ways to do so like using a VPN to access your private network. I can't think of a case in which you want to leave your database exposed through a public IP address. And doing so, would require some really good security policies.  It's just not a good solution

Comment: No one said they were going to expose their database through a public IP. Did you really read the question?

Comment: Enmanuel is right about it being a security flaw. So I will use nodeJS to build an API like he said. Even though i have no idea how to do that jeje

Comment: Node is a good choice, it's similar to Javascript so if you like that language you'll probably like Node. I you choose Node, I would recommend doing a REST service with Node + Express Framework. Good luck!